# Segmentation fault when using CMVision-based

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

I'm currently working with a computer vision project, and the problem lies in a function that takes a mode (for color) and a SEGMENTATION pointer as arguments. 
This is the segmentation class - http://pastebin.com/Z5D5pkqx
And this here if the piece of code that fails on me:

```
pair<cv::Point, cv::Point> blobFind(int mode, SEGMENTATION * segment){
SEGMENTATION segm(640, 480);
segment->EncodeRuns();
segment->ConnectComponents();
segment->ExtractRegions();
segment->SortRegions();
//cout << "& " << endl;
if(mode==1){
    //cout << "& " << endl;
int x1,x2,y1,y2;
if(segment->colors[ORANGE].list!=NULL){
    x1 = segment->colors[ORANGE].list->x1;
    y1 = segment->colors[ORANGE].list->y1;
    x2 = segment->colors[ORANGE].list->x2;
    y2 = segment->colors[ORANGE].list->y2;
    cout << y1 << endl;
    return make_pair(cv::Point(x1,x2), cv::Point(y1,y2));
    }
```

and the main up to calling this function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
IMAGE_CONTEXT *ic;
XEvent event;
cv::Mat image;
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640 );
cap.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480 );
height = 480;
width = 640;
pair<cv::Point, cv::Point> nxt;
SEGMENTATION segm( width, height );
SEGMENTATION * segment = &segm;
// Creating a new window
ic = new_window( "Video", 100, 100, width, height );
XImage *xImage1 = ic->xImage;
unsigned char *imageLine1 = (unsigned char*) xImage1 -> data;

while( !end ) {
    cap.read(image);
    data = image.data;
    segment->readThresholds("conf");
    segment->thresholdImage(data);
    nxt = blobFind(1, segment);
```

the segmentation fault occurs when the code reaches this point : segment->SortRegions(); inside the blobFind function. (segment->readThresholds("conf"); and segment->thresholdImage(data); used to be inside the function too, and then i gave the function data as an additional field.
Any clues what might be causing it? When I run the same sequence (encoderuns, connectcomponents, extractregions,sortregions) inside the main loop, it works perfectly.

Comment: You're asking people to look through a lot of code here.  You might get a better response if you cut it down to a minimal case which still demonstrates the problem.  (As a bonus, you might also spot the problem yourself in the course of doing this!)

Comment: From what I've gathered, it happens in the loop within SEGMENTATION::SortRegions, it crashes when it gets to the third color (orange).